# ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (291,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (291,6)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am creating an LSTM model to predict the traffic volume at certain times during the month. I want to then show the predicted vs true result on a time series graph.

I have managed to create a dataframe `df`. This dataframe will have 6 label features and 1 target value which will be called `Total`. This will represent the volume. I split my dataframe into two different arrays, where `X` represents the label features and `Y` represents the target value, as shown below:

```
X = df.drop(['Total', 'Date'], axis=1)
X = np.array(X)
Y = df['Total']
Y = np.array(Y)
```

The shape of X and  Y is `(1452, 6)` and `(1452,)` respectively. I then scale each array using the `MinMaxScaler()` function. This scales each value to a number between 0 & 1. The code I used is:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

scale_Y = scaler.fit_transform(Y.reshape(-1, 1))
scale_Y = scale_Y.reshape(-1)
scale_X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

I then reshaped the `scale_Y` to give me a 1-D array with the shape `(n_samples, )`. The data will be split into 80% for training and 20% for testing. This is done by:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scale_X, scale_Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

The `X_train` array is reshaped into the form `(n_samples, sequence_length, n_features)`. This is shown in the code below:

```
n_training_samples = len(X_train)
n_test_samples = len(X_test)
sequence_length = 1
n_features = X_train.shape[1]

training_batch_size = n_training_samples - sequence_length +1
test_batch_size = n_test_samples - sequence_length +1
n_samples_reshaped = n_training_samples // sequence_length
reshaped_data = X_train[:n_samples_reshaped * sequence_length].reshape((n_samples_reshaped, sequence_length, n_features))

X_test_reshaped = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1])
```

The inputs are then placed in:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=48, activation='tanh', input_shape=(sequence_length, n_features), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(units=24, activation= 'tanh', return_sequences=True, name="Hidden_layer_1"))
model.add(LSTM(units=24, name="Hidden_layer_2"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2, name="Dropout_layer"))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(reshaped_data, y_train, epochs=500, batch_size=20)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_reshaped)
```

After model training and testing has been completed, I want to plot the time series graph that will show predicted vs actual results. To attempt to do this I tried to use the `inverse_transform()` function so that the data can be put back into its original scale. The code I used is:

```
y_test_original_scale = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test)
```

This gave me an error message saying: `Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`. So then I tried:

```
y_test_original_scale = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))
```

This gave me an error message saying:

> ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (291,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (291,6)

I am new to machine learning and would really appreciate some assitance with correcting this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The last fit you did with your scaler object was on the x values

```
scale_X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

So when you go to do the inverse transform its being treated as x values.

Try creating two different scalars, for example

```
scaler_x = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_y = MinMaxScaler()
```

and fit each one separately. You can now apply the inverse transform of each on superstructure as well.